# CakePHP: cake bake all outputs code

Tags: php, cakephp, osx-yosemite, cakephp-bake, ampps

I'm using AMPPS with Yosemite for my first CakePHP app.  I downloaded CakePHP 3 using the AMPPS installer and the browser successfully renders the default home without any errors or issues.   When I try `cake bake all users` (as instructed in CakePHP tutorial) the console outputs the raw code in /Applications/AMPPS/www/MyApp/bin/cake
I tried using the OSX pre installed PHP and the one in /Applications/AMPPS/php5-5 and I get the same result both times.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968964/cakephp-3-on-bluehost-console-commands-do-not-function